# Unknown error in PowerBI Embedded by Javascript

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

When embedding a dashboard or a tile in Javascript I get this strange error from PowerBI.

The error comes from> [dashBoardEmbed minified javascript](https://content.powerapps.com/resource/powerbiwfe/scripts/dashboardEmbed.min.4a4b3b318b2bc635d2a5.js)

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Esri is not supported in Embedded scenario.
    at _ (powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.65d4a96bc46ec2fd3787.js:5)
    at powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.65d4a96bc46ec2fd3787.js:5
    at powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.65d4a96bc46ec2fd3787.js:5
    at t.invoke (powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.65d4a96bc46ec2fd3787.js:5)
    at Object.onInvoke (dashboardEmbed.min.4a4b3b318b2bc635d2a5.js:1)
    at t.invoke (powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.65d4a96bc46ec2fd3787.js:5)
    at e.run (powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.65d4a96bc46ec2fd3787.js:5)
    at powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.65d4a96bc46ec2fd3787.js:5
    at t.invokeTask (powerbiportal.dependencies.externals.bundle.min.65d4a96bc46ec2fd3787.js:5)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (dashboardEmbed.min.4a4b3b318b2bc635d2a5.js:1)
```

Is there anything I can do to not show this error? Or at least understand it?
I googled about Esri it seems that it is about ArcGIS Maps, but my dashboard or tile embedding scenario, doesnt contain any of this maps. Only contains a simple tile like this>
[image: Tile]

This error doesnt stop from embedding or even cause any bad experience for the user, but I just dont like too see this errors in the console. At most, I like to understand it :D
Anyone had this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your report to contain an argis module. Try to create a new page and remove the actual one. If the problem persists, desactivate the argis integration from the pbix.

Comment: You mean the report where the tiles from the dashboard comes from? I have disabled the ArcGis Maps for PowerBI in PowerBI desktop settings from the .pbix file and it still continues...

Comment: Yes it was the desactivation of the argis integration in powerbi desktop. Thanks.